# Using a POCO in MongoDB and Entity framework with spatial indexes

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

There are a couple classes in an external library that have a Coordinate property that needs to sometimes be stores in MongoDB and sometimes in SQL Server, ideally with spatial indexes, without having to modify the class.

MongoDB has no problem creating a geospatial spherical index on the Coordinate property with the following code:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<SomeClass>("SomeCollection")
collection.CreateIndex(IndexKeys<SomeClass>.GeoSpatialSpherical(x => x.Coordinate));
```

According to the documentation it will create the GeoJson point under the covers. I can then query the object as such:

```
var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(coordinate.Longitude, coordinate.Latitude));
var geoClause = Query<SomeClass>.Near(x => x.Coordinate, point, distance);
return collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => geoClause.Inject())
```

With SQL Server and EF, however, a DbGeography property would be needed for a spacial index.

What would be nice is if there's a extension point for mappings an object to a SQL data type in EF, but a Google search returned nothing of the like. Does such a thing exist?

I thought about a generic wrapper class, but EF doesn't support generics so that's not an option either, and I don't want to create a wrapper for every class.

Is my only option to extend the classes?